# Can I convert a key value string pair into an array?

Tags: php

Let's say I have the following string:

```
"name"=>"value","last"=>"name","amount"=>5
```

How can I put that string into $arr, or just grab the 'name' property?

Comment: Sorry how is this question unclear?

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way to do it:

```
$string = '"name"=>"value","last"=>"name","amount"=>5';

$array = array();
foreach(explode(',', $string) as $item) {
  list($key, $value) = explode('=>', $item);
  $array[trim($key, '"')] = trim($value, '"');
}

echo $array['name'];
```

This code splits the string on `,`. Then iterates through the parts and splits them again on `=>` to get the key and the value. Then it trims the quotes on assignment.

Comment: +1 Beat me by that much :P

Comment: Would this be an issue if some values had a comma in there?

Comment: @CurtisW Yes, it would be an issue. It would be very hard to parse that string properly then. How did you get this string?